# ORACLE Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**what problem in my code ,can any one fix it**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_level_employee
      BEGIN
          update employee
          set emplevel=2
          where emplevel=1 and add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date
      END;
      
execute update_level_employee
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `as` before begin. You can also use `is` instead of `as`. Also you need to use semicolon(;) after each statement. Try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_level_employee
as
      BEGIN
          update employee
          set emplevel=2
          where emplevel=1 and add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date;
      END;
      
execute update_level_employee;
```

Comment: still you , awesome :))

Comment: Thanks a lot. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

It should be semicolon after update sentence:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_level_employee is
      BEGIN
          update employee
          set emplevel=2
          where emplevel=1 and add_months(startdate,36)<=current_date;
      END;
```